# including <Gl/glut.h> in Visual studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, opengl, compiler-errors, freeglut

in my .c file i have this error:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h> <<<fatal error: GL/glut.h: No such file or directory
#include <math.h>
```

I put the freeglut library in my workspace folder and create a 3 .json files in my .vscode folder, they look like this:

**c_cpp_properties.json**

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "windows-clang-x64",
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "${workspaceFolder}/freeglut-3.4.0/include"
      ],
      "defines": [
        "_DEBUG",
        "UNICODE",
        "_UNICODE"
      ],
      "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.19041.0",
      "compilerPath": "C:/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
      "cStandard": "${default}",
      "cppStandard": "${default}",
      "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "C/C++ Runner: Debug Session",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "externalConsole": true,
      "cwd": "c:/PorFavorreeeee/MoreTeste",
      "program": "c:/PorFavorreeeee/MoreTeste/build/Debug/outDebug",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe arquivo de build ativo",
            "command": "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compilador: C:\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

i really don't know what to do for this to compile. I don't know the error is in the compilers I'm using or in the way I configured them in Vscode.

Comment: Your `c_cpp_properties.json` tells the VSCode IntelliSense environment where to find the GL files. But you don't tell the compiler in your `tasks.json` file. You need to pass the `-I` (upper-case i) to the compiler to tell it about non-standard include directories.

Comment: It's worked, very very thanks man!!!